# Use result of LISTAGG function as an input for another query

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

Given the following query:

```
SELECT M.Module_code,
       LISTAGG(P.Prerequisite_code, ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.Prerequisite_code) "Prerequisites"
FROM   Module M
       INNER JOIN Prerequisite P
       ON M.Module_code = P.Module_code
GROUP BY M.Module_code;
```

I have the following output

```
MODULE Prerequisites
------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IM234  IM233, MA232
```

Now, I would like to use the set of values of Prerequisites as an input for another SQL Query.

How can I do that?

I'm using JDBC with Oracle.

Thanks

Comment: Question is, what input does the other query need? Output of your Query is a string - so you need to work with that.

Comment: Do you need to know the individual values or just the concatenated string?  If it is the former then you may want to use `CAST( COLLECT( column_name ) AS collection_type )` rather than `LISTAGG`.

Comment: @sers so basically the second query needs to retrieve all rows whose prerequisite matches AT least one of the values in Prerequisites from the first query.

MT0, It's definitely the former - I'll try your solution

Comment: Seems, you are using LISTAGG where you don't need to ...

Comment: @sers to be more precise, here's what I want to do.
I would like to use the set of values of Prerequisites as an INPUT for a IN clause. How can I do that?

Comment: You could use the string as parameter for the query where the query looks like "select bla from table where x in (?)" - but I doubt if that's elegant ...